# How do I stop ST2 adding type="text/javascript" to the script tag?

Tags: sublimetext2

When I open a script tag in a HTML document with sublime text 2 it automatically adds the type="text/javascript" but I don't want it as it's not required in the HTML5 spec. How do I stop it doing this?

Comment: It may not be required, but that doesn't mean it's wrong...

Comment: but I dont want it so how do i stop it?

Answer (score 0):

preferences menu -> browse packages -> browse **HTML** floder -> open **html_completions.py** with any text editor->
replace the line

```
("script\tTag", "script type=\"${1:text/javascript}\">$0</script>"),
```

with

```
("script\tTag", "script>$0</script>"),
```